# Проблема с append JQuery

Tags: jquery

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="text"></textarea>

<span onclick="$('#text').append('CODE_SMILE');">SMILE</span>
```

CODE_SMILE добавляется в форму только если она пуста. Но что делать если в форме уже есть текст?

Answer (score 0):

```
<span class="button">SMILE</span>

$('.button').click(() => {
  const text = $('#text').val();
  const result = `${text} CODE_SMILE`;
  $('#text').val(result);
});
```